# He had a good time with his manager. If he asked for a raise, he would get it. And he got it - a real past conditional valid here?

Tags: conditionals

**Example 1**

> What was he to do? If he leg go of the van, the people inside would fall. If he didn't help the people in the water, they would freeze.

I am curious as to how this kind of conditional is used.

I read this in a story book.

I think it is a real past conditional.

Can this kind of conditional structure be applied to our everyday English?

**Example 2**

> When my brother was having dinner with his manager, he had a good time with him.
> If he asked for a raise, he would get it. And he asked and got it.

I feel like in real life, because usually you will have already got to know the result, you simply only use conditional to talk about a past event when you have to express a unreal situation in the past. I don't know whether example 2 makes sense or not.

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense to me. It looks odd to state the possibility and then the outcome, unless you bring his thoughts into it. "_He felt that_ if he asked for a raise, he would get it - so he asked [for one] and got it."

Comment: Where did you find these quotes?  To be honest, they're quite poor English. For example  "If he leg go of the van" It should be "let" not "leg".  The second example is not exactly wrong, but it's not great English either. It's just a bit awkward, not well written.

Comment: @BillyKerr Sorry, it was a typo. The quote is from a Spider-man story book. I don't know whether they are poor English except for the typo.

Comment: It's interesting that this is from Spiderman, the phrase "What was he to do?" sounds old-fashioned to me. It's grammatically correct, but not used commonly anymore. (I would say this as "What should he do?")